# Logical order of PHP queries

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I've just wrote some code for a basic outline of a page. It for a game I run, but looking at the code I feel I've written it in the wrong order, and that i'm executing more queries than I need to.

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bodyguards WHERE username='$u'");

    if($bg = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // if you have a bg
        if($bg[status] == "active") {
            echo "your bodyguard is $bg[bodyguard], kick him?";
        } else {
            echo "invite a bg?";
        }
    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bodyguards WHERE bodyguard='$u' AND status='active'");

        if($bg = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // if you are a bg
            echo "you are the bodyguard of $bg[username]";
        } else {
            //otherwise check if anyone has invited you

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bodyguards WHERE bodyguard='$u' AND status='invited'");

            while($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo "$temp[username] has invited you to be their bodyguard, accept or decline?";
            }
        }
    }
```

i'm only using one database table. if a player1 had a confirmed bodyguard (player2) the row would look like:

username => player1,
bodyguard => player2,
status => active.

would anyone here have written the code in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have done it in a single query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bodyguards WHERE username='$u' OR (bodyguard='$u' AND (status='active' OR status='invited')");

$bg = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if ($bg) { // check for empty result first, to prevent E_NOTICE
    if ($bg['username'] == $u) {
        if($bg['status'] == "active") {
            echo "your bodyguard is {$bg['bodyguard']}, kick him?";
        } else {
            echo "invite a bg?";
        }
    } else if ($bg['bodyguard'] == $u) {
        if ($bg['status'] == "active") {
            echo "you are the bodyguard of {$bg['username']}";
        } else if ($bg['status'] == "invited") {
            echo "{$bg['username']} has invited you to be their bodyguard, accept or decline?";
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: Make sure you are escaping `$u` if the data is supplied by a user, using `mysql_real_escape_string`. Also, make sure you quote your array indices to prevent PHP notices (i.e.: use `$bg['username']` instead of `$bg[username]`).

Comment: I still need the loop to show if the player has more than one invite.

Comment: $u is the username of the player viewing the page, sorry i forgot to mention. and yeah i recently moved servers and the new PHP conf started showing loads of notices as I'm in the habit of never quoting my array keys :/

Comment: @Juddling: Sorry I didn't see that last loop there. However, you can still make it in a single query, since the entire result is already loaded in $query. You just have to keep on doing `mysql_fetch_assoc` to fetch the next row and so on.

Comment: That is amazing! Thanks very much. Just wondering, why do you put {} around your variables?

Comment: It's a habit. You can pass arrays in string like you did (without the {}). However, if you have more than one level (i.e.: $array['foo']['bar']), you will **have to** put {} otherwise ['bar'] doesn't get evaluated and just ends up in the output as ['bar'] (literally). So, instead of having to change it later if I want to add another level, I just do it the first time around.

Comment: Ahh cool. I often use bbcodes next to an array, and it makes me think i'm doing it wrong: [b]$array[0][/b]. it does parse, but i always feel PHP will think its multi dimensional!

Comment: also that do while() loop, would it have shown the correct row to begin with, i've never used a do while loop but that looked as if it would have called mysql_fetch_assoc() for the second time before showing the row?

Comment: A `do...while` loop is essentially a `while` loop where the condition gets evaluated at the end, instead of at the beginning. Example: `while ($i++) { echo $i }` will print 1 at first, but `do { echo $i; } while ($i++);` will print 0 at first.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have a releationship between two entities in a table, I usually make another table to hold the relationship.

My **BodyGuardRelations** table might look like

```
[id] [userId] [bodyGuardUserId] [status]
1    27       55                Active
2    43       89                Invited
```